# How to turn URL into IP address using boost::asio?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, ip-address, resolve

So I need some way of turning given `Protocol://URLorIP:Port` string into string `ip` int `port` How to do such thing with boost ASIO and Boost Regex? Or is it possible - to get IP using [C++ Net Lib](http://cpp-netlib.github.com/) (boost candidate) - notice - we do not need long connection - only IP.

So I currently use such code for parsing

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) return 0;

    std::vector<std::string> values;
    boost::regex expression(
        //   proto                 host               port
        "^(\?:([^:/\?#]+)://)\?(\\w+[^/\?#:]*)(\?::(\\d+))\?"
        //   path                  file       parameters
        "(/\?(\?:[^\?#/]*/)*)\?([^\?#]*)\?(\\\?(.*))\?"
    );
    std::string src(argv[1]);
    if (boost::regex_split(std::back_inserter(values), src, expression))
    {
        const char* names[] = {"Protocol", "Host", "Port", "Path", "File", 
                "Parameters", NULL};
        for (int i = 0; names[i]; i++)
            printf("%s: %s\n", names[i], values[i].c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What shall I add to my small program to parse URL into IP?

Comment: Basically, you first need to parse your protocol string (independently of its meaning) then, once you have the host part, you have to perform a name resolution (I would use `getaddrinfo` for that). Since I don't know boost ASIO, I won't put this as an answer but merely as an advice.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Remember that there may be multiple IP addresses for any one hostname, boost gives you an iterator that will go through them.

The use is fairly straightforward, add this before `return 0;` of your program:

```
std::cout << "IP addresses: \n";
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(values[1], "");
for(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator i = resolver.resolve(query);
                            i != boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator();
                            ++i)
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint end = *i;
    std::cout << end.address() << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

and don't forget `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`

test run:

```
~ $ g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -ansi -o test test.cc -lboost_regex -lboost_system -lboost_thread
~ $ ./test http://www.google.com:7777
Protocol: http
Host: www.google.com
Port: 7777
Path:
File:
Parameters:
IP addresses:
74.125.226.179 74.125.226.176 74.125.226.178 74.125.226.177 74.125.226.180
```

PS: For reference, I called

- TCP resolver's [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/basic_resolver.html)
- query's [host/service constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver_query/basic_resolver_query/overload3.html) with a don't-care service value of `""`
- the exception-throwing [form of resolve()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver/resolve/overload1.html)
- [dereferenced the iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver_iterator/operator__star_.html) to get a resolver entry
- used resolver_entry's [type conversion to endpoint](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver_entry/operator_endpoint_type.html)
- used the TCP endpoint's [address() accessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint/address/overload1.html)
- used [operator<<](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/operator_lt__lt_.html) to show the address: you could use [to_string()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v4/to_string/overload1.html) instead, if needed.