# Find machine IP adress from machine name

Tags: c++, boost, wxwidgets

I know the remote machine name, this machine is on the same network.

If I ping that machine from command prompt, I get the IP information as well.

```
C:\Users\anikumar>ping neemqx01g

Pinging neemqx01g.efi.internal [10.210.98.194] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.210.98.194: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.210.98.194: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.210.98.194: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 10.210.98.194: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 10.210.98.194:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 0ms
```

How can I achieve programmatically in wxWidgets or boost to get the IP address?

**Answer:**

***C function:***

```
const wxString GetIPbyName(const wxString& name)
{
    struct hostent* pHostInfo;
    pHostInfo = gethostbyname(name.c_str());

    in_addr * address = (in_addr *)pHostInfo->h_addr;
    std::string ip_address = inet_ntoa(*address);

    return ip_address;
}
```

***wxWidgets:***

```
   wxIPV4address ipv4;
   ipv4.Hostname(m_currentServer);
   wxString m_currentServer = ipv4.IPAddress();
```

I am not how above will behave in case of multiple active network cards.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486113/boost-asio-how-to-turn-url-into-ip-adress

Comment: @YamMarcovic: The OP is not asking about URIs, nor about Boost.ASIO.

Comment: I am voting to close as a resource request.

Comment: @PreferenceBean I don't think there is such a component in a purely GUI framework; but the answer in the link covered resolving hostnames with asio which is portable (as you ended up recommending yourself).

Answer (score 2):

I've looked through the documentation for you and, **you can't**.

For portable network name lookups you could consider making use of a general-purpose cross-platform networking library, such as *Boost.ASIO*.

Comment: could you please post a code snippet.

Comment: Huh? "How can I do this?" -> "No, it doesn't." ???

Comment: @immibis: Yeah, okay ;)

Answer (score 1):

C socket library is (almost) portable. You will have the old `gethostbyaddr` call or the newer `getaddrinfo` one.

But you will need some `#ifdef` to make them truely portable because:

- headers are not the same `netdb.h` (and optionaly sys/types.h and sys/socket.h) on a Posix system and `Ws2tcpip.h` and `winsock2.h` on Windows
- on windows, you need a call to `WSAStartup` to initialize winsock.

Comment: And this is why we let well-tested, widely-used libraries do that for us.